# Apply attribute to property get/set methods via batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to automate the generation and cleanup of partial classes created using the .net framework's XSD too.  My main problem is that [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()] affects the code in my partial class as well as the automatically generated one.  I can delete the offending attribute in the same  batch file that I use to create the files.

However I don't want to be stepping into all of the autogenerated file's properties.  I can stop the debugger from entering each property by applying [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()] to the get and set methods.  Can I do this via a batch file? without needing to install/configure a third party scripting language to do the text processing?

Example property with attributes added:

```
public string FileFormatVersion
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
    get { 
    return this.fileFormatVersionField;
    }
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
    set
    {
        this.fileFormatVersionField = value;
    }
}
```

Link to deleting lines via a batch file (first part of the needed cleanup)
[Delete certain lines in a txt file via a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file)

Comment: Wait, did I misunderstand?  Someone added a link to deleting lines from a batch file, but it sounded to me like you wanted them added to getters and setters...

Comment: No.  The link was mine, and was how to do the 1st step of the cleanup process.  I added an edit to clarify its intent.  The other persons edit was just to tweak formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set outfile=%1.copy
del "%outfile%"
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%1) do (
    set line=%%x
    if "!line: =!"=="get{" (
        echo [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough^(^)]>>%outfile%
    )
    if "!line: =!"=="set{" (
        echo [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough^(^)]>>%outfile%
    )
    echo.%%x>>%outfile%
)
```

This is simplistic, and won't handle cases like properties that already have the attribute added.  It also might choke on some lines of code, but I haven't found a line that does yet.

[Edit] Made the changes mentioned below, except for the extra echo indentation (would just look ugly on this page).

Comment: The XSD tool's output is very circumscribed in format so I was able to dispense with two of your cases.  I added 12 spaces into the echo's to properly indent the attributes, and changed the last echo to properly output blank lines instead of the text "ECHO is on".

Comment: My revised version of your batch file (since I don't have the rep to edit your post directly).

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set outfile=%1.Xsd.cs
del "%outfile%"
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%1.Xsd.cs.temp) do (
    set line=%%x
    if "!line: =!"=="get{" (
        echo             [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough^(^)]>>%outfile%
    )
    if "!line: =!"=="set{" (
        echo             [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough^(^)]>>%outfile%
    )
    echo.%%x>>%outfile%
)

Answer (score 0):

I know you'd like to use a .bat file but I really think python or another scripting language is your best bet here.

Comment: If it was the only option perhaps, but adding an additional tool to the dev process for a tertiary priority task is a bit of overkill when not needed IMO.