# Can an Attribute be set only on the Setter of an Auto-Implemented Property?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Currently I have this:

```
[SomeCustomAttribute]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

However, I want this attribute to decorate only the setter, not the getter.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Based on the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161427/apply-attribute-to-property-get-set-methods-via-batch-file), I'm inclined to say that you probably could, though I've never had a reason to do it in practice.

Comment: getter and setter are actually methods, so why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Syntactically, the following is allowed:

```
 public string Name { get; [SomeCustomAttribute] set; }
```

The rest is up to (your?) `SomeCustom` Attribute.

It would of course have to be a method attribute, not a property attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    [SomeCustomAttribute]
    set;
}
```