# Batch File/Script to delete Several non sequential lines from text file(s)

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file

I have read the suggestion listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file).

The batch file solution seems to work untill I get to about 5 ignore conditional strings and then the output starts to ignore very large sections of the text files(s) even things it shouldn't.

Basically, I have a bunch of Windows systeminfo (run > cmd > systeminfo) parses. If you run the system info util you will see several lines there (200+). I want a way to run through them (directory at a time hopefully) and only keep or parse out about the 10 lines that matter (CPU speed, RAM amt, etc.).

Like I said, I tried the solution above and it looked great until I got past a few ignore strings and all of a sudden it just started ignoring almost everything.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Or even an idea as to what I was doing wrong?

This is what I got up to before I realized that lines that should not have been deleted were not being printed,

```
type *.txt | findstr /v "OS Manufacturer:" | findstr /v "OS Configuration:" | findstr /v "OS Build Type:" | findstr /v "Product ID:" | findstr /v "Original Install Date:" | findstr /v "System Up Time:" | findstr /v "System type:" | findstr /v "BIOS Version:" | findstr /v "Windows Directory:" | findstr /v "System Directory:" | findstr /v "Boot Device:" | findstr /v "System Locale:" | findstr /v "Input Locale:" | findstr /v "Time Zone:" | findstr /v "Available Physical Memory:" | findstr /v "Virtual Memory: Max Size:" | findstr /v "Virtual Memory: Available:" | findstr /v "Virtual Memory: In Use:" | findstr /v "Page File Location(s):" | findstr /v "Domain:" | findstr /v "Logon Server:" | findstr /v "Hotfix(s):" | findstr /v "NetWork Card(s):" | findstr /v "Registered Owner:" | findstr /v "Registered Organization:"  > c:\zzz\final.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the script I ended up with. I thank ghost greatly because he pointed me in a great direction. I'm someone that does not do scripting at all but I was able to figure it out.

The code post function is mangling this mangled mess even more but it is working.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")    
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")    
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
Set colComputerSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
Const ForAppending = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For Each objComputerSystem in colComputerSystems
            dim txtfilename
            txtfilenamepc = objComputerSystem.Name
        dim longuser
        longuser = objComputerSystem.UserName
        dim myArray
        MyArray = Split(longuser,"\")
        dim shortuser
                if MyArray(2) = "" then shortuser = MyArray(1) else shortuser = MyArray(2)
    next
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    ("\\hqfs01\TSUInstall\tools\damir\pcinfologs\" & shortuser & "-" & txtfilenamepc & ".txt", ForAppending, True)
For Each objComputerSystem in colComputerSystems

    objTextFile.WriteLine "User Name: " & shortuser
    objTextFile.WriteLine "Computer Name: " & objComputerSystem.Name
    objTextFile.WriteLine "Model: " & objComputerSystem.Model

    dim ramraw, ramdivider
    ramdivider = 1048576
    ramraw = objComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory
    objTextFile.WriteLine "RAM: " & ramraw\ramdivider & " MB"
    Next
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    objTextFile.WriteLine "Operating System: " & objOperatingSystem.Caption
    objTextFile.WriteLine "Service Pack: " & objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion
    Next
objTextFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

please get a proper tool for parsing text. if you can afford to use tools like gawk (for windows), here's how you can do it , EASILY.

```
C:\test>systeminfo | gawk -F":" "/BIOS|Processor|<things i want>/{print $2}"
```

or if you can't afford to download stuff, M$ provided us with vbscript, which is way better than batch for doing things like this. Here's an example and not exhaustive solution

```
Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")    
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")    
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    Wscript.Echo "Boot Device: " & objOperatingSystem.BootDevice
    Wscript.Echo "Build Number: " & objOperatingSystem.BuildNumber
    Wscript.Echo "Build Type: " & objOperatingSystem.BuildType
    Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & objOperatingSystem.Caption
    Wscript.Echo "Code Set: " & objOperatingSystem.CodeSet
    Wscript.Echo "Country Code: " & objOperatingSystem.CountryCode
    Wscript.Echo "Debug: " & objOperatingSystem.Debug
    Wscript.Echo "Install Date: " & dtmInstallDate 
    Wscript.Echo "Licensed Users: " & objOperatingSystem.NumberOfLicensedUsers
    Wscript.Echo "Organization: " & objOperatingSystem.Organization
    Wscript.Echo "OS Language: " & objOperatingSystem.OSLanguage
    Wscript.Echo "OS Product Suite: " & objOperatingSystem.OSProductSuite
    Wscript.Echo "OS Type: " & objOperatingSystem.OSType
    Wscript.Echo "Primary: " & objOperatingSystem.Primary
    Wscript.Echo "Registered User: " & objOperatingSystem.RegisteredUser
    Wscript.Echo "Serial Number: " & objOperatingSystem.SerialNumber
    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objOperatingSystem.Version
Next
```

Others you can use , for example to get Bios information is Win32_Bios, Win32_PhysicalMemory,  Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray for memory info, etc . Please research MSDN vbscript or simple google the various WMI you can use to get computer hardware information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `findstr` handles spaces in the search string a little different:

> Use spaces to separate multiple search
>   strings unless the argument is
>   prefixed with `/C`.  For example,
>   `'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y'` searches
>   for `"hello"` or `"there"` in file `x.y`. 
>   `'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y'`
>   searches for `"hello there"` in file
>   `x.y`.

So your long chain of `findstr`s would ignore every line that contain even a single work from any one search string. You can prefix the search strings with `/C` to avoid that:

```
type *.txt | findstr /v /c:"OS Manufacturer:" | findstr /v /c:"OS Configuration:" | ...
```

Also a problem is that the search strings may appear anywhere in the line with above syntax. You can anchor them to the start of the line by using regular expressions:

```
type *.txt | findstr /r /v /c:"^OS Manufacturer:" | findstr /r /v /c:"^OS Configuration:" | ...
```

The `^` acts as *anchor* and tells `findstr` to match this only at the start of a line. But when using regex you have to escape some characters, such as a dot.

Answer (score -1):

Odds are your problem is simply that your command line is too long. Try breaking the filtering up in several parts, with intermediate files in between.

Comment: There are no variable expansions which could cause this and the maximum command-line length limit in cmd is 8190 characters.