# Remove multi-line strings from a text file using a batch script

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will edit a text file to remove lines that contain a certain string **and** remove the line directly after that.
An example of this file would look like this:

```
LINE ENTRY KEEP_1 BLA BLA
END
LINE ENTRY REMOVE_1 FOO BAR
END
LINE ENTRY REMOVE_2 HELLO WORLD
END
LINE ENTRY KEEP_2 CAT DOG
END
```

After running the batch script I require the new file to contain

```
LINE ENTRY KEEP_1 BLA BLA
END
LINE ENTRY KEEP_2 CAT DOG
END
```

where any line containing REMOVE_ has been deleted, as well as the corresponding 'END' line.

I have tried using the technique found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file) to remove the lines containing the string but it does not appear to be possible to include characters such as \r\n to check for and include the 'END' in the search. I can't do this as 2 seperate FINDSTR commands as I still require the 'END' text to be kept for the other two entries.
Using `findstr /v REMOVE_` leaves me with the following:

```
LINE ENTRY KEEP_1 BLA BLA
END
END
END
LINE ENTRY KEEP_2 CAT DOG
END
```

and using `findstr /v "REMOVE_*\r\nEnd"` does not seem to work at all.
Just to confirm each line is definitely terminated with `\r\n`.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely constrained to a batch script? Could you use awk, for example?

Comment: I'm not limited to batch, however this file may need to be run on a number of different machines so I would like to keep dependencies to a minimum if possible. Ideally either batch or VBS I guess.

Comment: In this case I'd suggest VBS, since you'll likely have fewer sorrows that way. I'm not entirely sure it *can't* be done reliably but I do struggle with such things myself from time to time and didn't find a good general solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following batch script should do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A REMOVE_COUNT=1

if "%~2"=="" (
    echo Usage: %~n0 search_str file
    echo remove lines that contain a search_str and remove %REMOVE_COUNT% line^(s^) directly after that
    exit /b 1
)

set "SEARCH_STR=%~1"
set "SRC_FILE=%~2"

set /A SKIP_COUNT=0
for /F "skip=2 delims=[] tokens=1,*" %%I in ('find /v /n "" "%SRC_FILE%"') do (
    if !SKIP_COUNT! EQU 0 (
        set SRC_LINE=%%J
        if defined SRC_LINE (
            if "!SRC_LINE:%SEARCH_STR%=!" == "!SRC_LINE!" (
                echo.!SRC_LINE!
            ) else (
                set /A SKIP_COUNT=%REMOVE_COUNT%
            )
        ) else (
            rem SRC_LINE is empty
            echo.
        )
    ) else (
        set /A SKIP_COUNT-=1
    )
)
```

The number of lines to be removed after a matched line can be configured by setting the `REMOVE_COUNT` variable.

The script also handles files with empty lines correctly by using a trick: The find command is used to prefix all lines with line numbers. That way the for command will not skip empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` operates line-wise. You cannot do anything with it that spans more than a single line.

In any case, you're in for a world of pain if you do this with batch files. While you certainly *can* loop through the file and only output certain lines, this would look kinda like the following:

```
set remove=
for /f %%x in (file.txt) do (
  if not defined remove (
    echo %%x|findstr "REMOVE" >nul 2>&1 && set remove=1
    if not defined remove echo.%%x
  ) else (
    set remove=
  )
)
```

(untested, but might work). The problem here is twofold: `for /f` removes any empty lines from the output so if your file had them before you won't have them afterwards. This may or may not be a problem for your specific case. Another problem is that dealing with special characters can get hairy. I give no guarantee that the above works as it should for things like `>`, `<`, `&`, `|`, ...

Your best bet in this case, if you need to run it on almost any Windows machine, would probably be a VBScript. The string handling capabilities are much more robust there.

Comment: `grep` can take `-A` or `-B` to include lines after and/or before!

Comment: you started about `grep`. Just trying to help dude. Relax.