# <Batch> How to find a line in file and add few lines under it?

Tags: html, command-line, batch-file, find, replace

I'm trying to find a line

```
"<!-- here comes the new post -->"
```

in an HTML file and add some lines that will contain some vars and special characters like <>#"" below it, without replacing the lines that are already below, because the line
will be always in the middle of the file.

--David

Comment: This gets asked practically every day, please do a little searching first. If you must post, you'll want people to know if you are doing this with Linux/Unix or on Windows. Tags to search for would be xmlstartlet, perl, sed, awk. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Remove multi-line strings from a text file using a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279431/remove-multi-line-strings-from-a-text-file-using-a-batch-script?answertab=active#tab-top).
If you can remove lines you should be also be able to insert lines.