# delete file name by dragging it into bat file

Tags: batch-file, find

I would like to delete a file name from a txt list ussing a drag and drop function however i cant get my code to work

```
:delete
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p dnr=%1
find /v "!dnr!" document.txt > deleted.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the file you drag and drop onto it, from the text file (presuming name and extension format). If it's full path format then change the `%%~nxa` to `%%a`.

```
:delete
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%1") do (
set dnr=%%~nxa
find /v "!dnr!" filenames.txt >deleted.txt 
)    
for /f "skip=2 tokens=* delims=" %%x in (deleted.txt) do echo %%x >>new.txt
del deleted.txt /f /q
ren new.txt deleted.txt
```

Comment: This works fine, however the deleted.txt text file has  that annoying 
---------- C:\FILENAMES.TXT at the begining of it is there a way to supress this or get rid of it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to get rid of it. It's only 3 extra lines, it would be better if they had a `find` switch that would not include it though!

Comment: actually it was onther post of yours on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428692/batch-file-to-delete-first-3-lines-of-a-text-file