# Dealing with the Header Line of the Single/Multiple Coloumn Variable List

Tags: batch-file

Presently we have been using the below mentioned script for some activity; but if we have any header of the specific variable list, how could I ignore it (first line of the variable file)...?

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a n=0
set /a m=0
set /a nline=1
set /a mod=0
for /f %%i in (C:\VariableList\Variable.txt) do (
  set /a n=m+1
  set /a m=n
  set /a mod=m%%%nline%
  if !mod! EQU 0 (
    run -n -D %%I
    if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
      goto end
    )
  )
)
:end
endlocal
```

Comment: `for /f` has a "skip=n" option. See `for /?`

Comment: Thanks Michael, but it will be very helpful if you comment the `entire line`.

Comment: Use an outer `for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%L in (file.txt)` loop to get the lines, then feed it to your main loop `for /f %%i in ("%%L")`.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm for your reply, but can you please post the `entire /f loop part` for `single & multiple (token)`column.

Comment: How about this one....? `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428692/batch-file-to-delete-first-3-lines-of-a-text-file (1-line)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Innovative Idea, if you filter some query by  Find `c:\windows\system32\find "Z",`though it's not necessary because it's already coming into the simple query result (for which is common into the all variable), and then use `c:\windows\system32\find /V "X/Y/Z",` though it's not require to get your desire result (for which is not common into the all other variable); magically `Header part will be Vanished`.