# Simple way to delete one line from file using command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am writing a simple batch script, and I need to delete one line from the file that gets downloaded by the script. What is the easiest way to do this using ONLY the command prompt? I have come across several various suggestions, but nothing to very simply delete one string that is constant across all files that are downloaded with the script.

Comment: Do you know the line content? Does it occurs only once? If so, you could try using findstr /v to create a new file without that line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very platform dependant question. If you are using a *nix environment (Linux / Mac environment using bash / shell), you can accomplish this with sed

```
sed '/${regular_expression_that_matches_line_to_be_removed}/d' yourFile.txt > newFile.txt
```

This will generate a new file called `newFile.txt` that will contain the output. You can also do this in place (it modifies the file it's using as input), but I recommend against that because if you mess up your regex, you've lost your input.

If you're using a Windows environment (which I assume you are due to your batch-file tag), try looking at this [Delete certain lines in a txt file via a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file)

Comment: Yes, this is Windows. Thanks for the link. I thought there may be a different way without rewriting the file, but it will do!