# Delete certain lines in a txt file via a batch file based on column position value match

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, delete-row

I have a text file that has fixed length data.

```
1234|test1|2015|Who are you
4567|test2||I'm a dumb guy
1234|test1|2015|We all know
```

I just need to remove line 2 by checking if position 12th value <> 2 (current year so will always be 2 for all rows until 2099 :)) then remove that line. In other words, just fetch rows which contains value 2 in position 12.

I tried searching and found this but I dont know how to re-write to look for a position = value.

type file.txt | findstr /v ERROR | findstr /v REFERENCE

[Delete certain lines in a txt file via a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file)

Thanks so much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findstr /r "...........2" "Data.txt"
```

See `findstr /?` for help. Also `help`.

Redirect output to a file.

```
findstr /r "...........2" "c:\folder\Data.txt" > "c:\folder\Output.txt"
```

See [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch) for punctuation help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `/v /r`?

Comment: He wants to keep 2nnn not lose 2nnn. This is better `^...........2[0-9][0-9][0-9]`