# Deleting line after line in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a Batch-script which copies a file to multiple servers. It takes the servername from a `.txt` file as a variable and uses it to connect to the server.
After a name was turned into a variable, I want to remove this entry from the file (and save it to another file) so that the Script takes the next available server name when running again.

So far, I have written this:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p servername=<server.txt
findstr /v "%servername%" server.txt > serverdone.txt

rem (Part of the script that copies the file, this is already working)

GOTO start
```

The script is able to take the first line of `server.txt` and puts it in the `%servername%` variable as supposed, however, the `findstr` line does not seem to work. The `serverdone.txt` file stays empty, and the script just keeps using the first server in the `server.txt` file. I used this question as a guide: [Delete certain lines in a txt file via a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file).

Comment: Why not simply walking through the file `server.txt` with a `for /F` loop and do the copying part for each line?

Comment: @aschipfl You mean FOR /F %%G IN (server.txt) DO set /p servername=<server.txt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not use a `for /F` loop to read the file `server.txt` line by line and do the copying stuff within that loop? I think this could perfectly work for you. Take a look at the following example:

```
@echo off

rem This iterates through all lines of `server.txt`:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%S in ("server.txt") do (

    rem Call copying sub-routine for each item:
    call :SUB_COPY %%S

)
exit /B

:SUB_COPY
rem (do your copying stuff here, using `%1`)
exit /B
```

The copying stuff could also be placed within the `for /F` loop directly (using `%%S` instead of `%1`).

---

In case the copying stuff could fail and you want `server.txt` to contain all server names for which it failed and `serverdone.txt` to contain those for which it succeeded, you could do this:

```
@echo off

rem This iterates through all lines of `server.txt`;
rem `type` ensures the file to be read completely
rem before the any further activities are pursued;
rem `break` does nothing and is used to empty files:
for /F "delims=" %%S in ('
    type "server.txt" ^& ^
        ^> "server.txt" break ^
        ^> "serverdone.txt" break
') do (

    rem Call copying sub-routine for each item:
    call :SUB_COPY %%S
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        rem (`ErrorLevel` is `>=1`, so failure)
        >> "server.txt" echo %%S
    ) else (
        rem (`ErrorLevel` is `0`, so success)
        >> "serverdone.txt" echo %%S
    )

)
exit /B

:SUB_COPY
rem (do your copying stuff here, using `%1`;
rem  in case of errors, set `ErrorLevel`)
exit /B 0 & rem (success: `ErrorLevel` is `0`)
exit /B 1 & rem (failure: `ErrorLevel` is `1`)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me out. Cheers