# Only keeping lines in a textfile that start with specific characters

Tags: batch-file, text

How can we achieve deleting lines starting with specific characters in a huge text file using a batch file?

e.g:

oldfile.txt is:

line 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam

line 2 euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

line 3 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor

line 4  vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla.

deleting lines starting with "eui" and "ali";

newfile.txt becomes:

line 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam

line 4  vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla.

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i prefer learning through experiencing if you don't mind!

Comment: Actually I do mind, because your post is not a real question (following the rules of this site) but a task request! Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! So try it on your own and when stuck, come back here, share your efforts and ask a specific question!

Comment: i tried but i couldn't. be cool, task is not yours!

Comment: No worries, I am cool... The thing is, questions that are not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are likely volted to be closed...

Comment: thanks. if you havent wasted my time -and yours- and replied a simple answer, i would now be working on the topics of my profession. i am intelligent enough to be aware of here is not a free coding service.

Comment: Funny (sarcastic), there's always something going down in the comments these days. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: @AkınAktansel - And yet you're not intelligent enough to not post an off-topic question. [RTFM](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Jonas  but what is the batch file exactly for  removing lines starting with eui and ali, not Lorem and euismod? yes man as you guessed, this was a sarcastic joke :) thanks for your gracious support, it works perfect!

Comment: @SomethingDark  there is something dark about you, sorry to bother everyone, i am new and will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@ECHO ON
findstr /v "Lorem euismod" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test.txt" > "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\outfile.txt"
PAUSE
```

It deletes `line 1` and `line 2` in `test.txt`. I used `Lorem` `euismod` as reference.

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/delete-certain-lines-in-a-txt-file-via-a-batch-file).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid deleting lines with one or more of the search terms in the middle of the string somewhere, instead of just at the beginning as requested, add the /B option to fix that:

```
findstr /B /V "eui ali" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```